# ERROR : While using splitting the dataset for providing to machine learning algorithms

Tags: python, machine-learning, runtime-error, cross-validation

Its very strange as this error is occurring only for particular 3 columns and works fine with other columns .

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/version1/analyze.py", line 447, in <module>
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train,cv=kfold, scoring=scoring) 

 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 140, in cross_val_score
    for train, test in cv_iter)

fac = 1. / (n_samples - n_classes)

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

## MY CODE :

```
validation_size = 0.20
seed = 10
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation =   model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=validation_size, random_state=seed)
seed = 10
scoring = 'accuracy'

kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)

cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train,cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)  #error occurs here
```

The above error occurs only if i select few particular columns from my dataset , it works well for other columns !

All columns have same no of data and similar kind of values .

```
 #code for Split-out validation dataset
   array = dataset.values

   if field == "rh":
     X = array[:,0:8]

   elif field == "rm":
     X = array[:,0:8]

   elif field == "wh":
     X = array[:,0:8]

   elif field == "wm":
     X = array[:,0:8]

   else :
    print"wrong field"

  if field == "rh":
      Y = array[:,0]     #works fine , even for 4,5,6,7 it works 

  elif field == "rm":      #gives the above error only for 1,2,3
      Y = array[:,1]      #gives the above error

  elif field == "wh":     #gives the above error
      Y = array[:,2]

  elif field == "wm":     #gives the above error
      Y = array[:,3]

  else :
      print"wrong field"
```

This is my dataset :

```
      index,1column,2 column,3column,….,8column
         0,238,240,1103,409,1038,4,67,0
         1,41,359,995,467,1317,8,71,0
         2,102,616,1168,480,1206,7,59,0
         3,0,34,994,181,1115,4,68,0
         4,88,1419,1175,413,1060,8,71,0
         5,826,10886,1316,6885,2086,263,119,0
         6,88,472,1200,652,1047,7,64,0
         7,0,322,957,533,1062,11,73,0
         8,0,200,1170,421,1038,5,63,0
         9,103,1439,1085,1638,1151,29,66,0
        10,0,1422,1074,4832,1084,27,74,0
        11,1828,754,11030,263845,1209,10,79,0
        12,340,1644,11181,175099,4127,13,136,0
        13,71,1018,1029,2480,1276,18,66,1
        14,0,3077,1116,1696,1129,6,62,0

             “”””””
             ‘”””””
```

Total 105 data records

But the above error does not occur for 1 column , that is when Y = 1 column,
But the above same error happens when i choose any other column 2 , 3 or 4 .

Comment: `n_samples - n_classes` can't be zero

Comment: @VMRuiz  yes , but how to handle this ?

Comment: Try changing `validation_size` or adding more samples. It's hard to guess without running your code or knowing your dataset

Comment: @VMRuiz  no use if i change Validation_size , I have added my dataset in the question.

Comment: There you have the reason: the number of different values in columns 1,2, 3 and 4 its the same than the number of samples after validation_split (105*0.2).  Could you make a count distinct over each column to check this?

Comment: @VMRuiz Am just a beginner i machine learning , can you tell what i need to do exactly please ? What is actually wrong here , How is it working with 0,4,5,6,7  but not working with 1,2,3 ?

Comment: @VMRuiz Also i have split-ed using if condition , so how does this have a effect on other columns ? ill be using only one column at a time .

Comment: Values assigned to `Y` are the class values. Each different value is a different class. Depending on the selected column - 0, 1, 2, ... , 7 - , you are using a different set of values, where its length is the value `n_classes`. Its just happend to be that for some of the columns, the set of values will cause that `n_samples == n_classes` and therefore you get the error.

Comment: Now i understood what is n_classes , What is n_samples ? Any idea on how to handle this ?  @VMRuiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n_samples are the rows in the dataset and n_classes are the unique class labels in your label array. The Error above was occuring because the dataset had no label classes in it !